# Why won't this button alter the text box?

Tags: javascript, html, calculator

I programmed a calculator and when you click the button to insert text it doesn't insert text into the box. Plese help me find the issue.
Here is the code:

```
<html>
<head>
<style type=text/css>
#calculator{
    margin-top:10%;
    margin-left:37%;
    background:cyan;
    color:black;
    height:350px;
    width:350;
    padding:50px;
    text-align:center;
    border:5px dashed blue;
}
#calculator b{
    color:black;
}

</style>
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
var num1 = getElementById("number1");
var num2 = getElementById("number2").value;;
var op = getElementById("operation").value;;
var ans = getElementById("answer").value;
function type1(){
    if(num1 != ""){
        num1 = "1";
    }
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id=calculator>
<center>
<table>
<tr><td><input type="text" value=""  placeholder="Number 1"  id="number1"   readonly="readonly" maxlength="1" tabindex="1"/></td></tr><tr><td>
<input type="text" value=""  placeholder="Operation" id="operation" maxlength="1" readonly="readonly" tabindex="2"/></td></tr><tr><td>
<input type="text" value=""  placeholder="Number 2"  id="number2"   maxlength="1" readonly="readonly" tabindex="3"/><b>=</b></td></tr><tr><td>
<input type="text" value=""  placeholder="Answer"    id="answer"    tabindex="4"   readonly="readonly"/></td></tr>
<table>
<tr><td><input type="button" value="1" onClick="type1()"</td><td><input type="button" value="2" onClick="type2()"</td><td><input type="button" value="3" onClick="type3()"</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="button" value="4" onClick="type4()"</td><td><input type="button" value="5" onClick="type5()"</td><td><input type="button" value="6" onClick="type6()"</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="button" value="7" onClick="type7()"</td><td><input type="button" value="8" onClick="type8()"</td><td><input type="button" value="9" onClick="type9()"</td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="button" value="- " onClick="type-()"></td><td><input type="button" value="0" onClick="type0()"></td><td><input type="button" value="+" onClick="type+()"></td></tr>
<tr><td><input type="button" value="X" onClick="typeX()"></td><td><input type="button" value="=" onClick="type=()"></td><td><input type="button" value="/ " onClick="type/()"></td></tr>
</table>
<p><b>NOTE:</b>This widget does not support negative numbers.</p>
</center>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Here it is in action:
http://test342.coffeecup.com/LearningJavascript.html
Thank You for the help!

Comment: please open the developer console in your browser. there you can see a lot of errors that you can correct easily. for example: document.getElementById not only getElementById, or: type2 is not defined...

Answer (score 1):

**1** Replace `var num1 = getElementById("number1");` with `var num1 = getElementById("number1").value;`

For the other buttons, there are no functions defined for them.

**2** Replace `getElementById` with `document.getElementById` (just adding this, **Bigood** had it first.)

Answer (score 1):

First, `getElementById()` is a method of `document` object.

Use `document.getElementById()` instead ([see reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementById)).

Secondly, you shouldn't declare one function for each button: you'd rather use one function for each type of interaction, as *number* and *operation*.

Then, in your `onclick` attributes, use the correct function to call, and change the focused input if an operation is done.

Thirdly, don't use semicolons twice, it isn't safer :)